# Link to open a LaTeX file

Tags: hyperref

How can you create a link with `hyperref` in a PDF file to open a LaTeX file?

Comment: If you prefer to discuss your question in german, consider asking at [golatex.de](http://golatex.de) or [mrunix.de](http://mrunix.de/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=38).

Comment: I asked a similar question, but for pdf files on record in bibtex database. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86189/advanced-link-in-bibliography

Answer (score 9):

The trick is to use `run:/.` like

```
\href{run:./myFile.pdf}{LinkText}
```

To make a Link to the PDF `myFile.pdf` in the same directory as the LaTeX file (more precisely the created PDF from that file). It is then opened in the PDF-Viewer thats standard for viewing PDFs on that specific system.

*Edit*
I had that in my file to Link to a TeX file, of course that works the same way

```
\href{run:./myFile.tex}{LinkText}
```

It should then open in the standard editor for `.tex` files. Thanks for mentioning in the comments.

Comment: Whether or not this works is of course viewer dependent, and in Adobe requires disabling "Enhanced security".

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I needed. The remark is correct, that the matter is viewer dependent. With Adobe it works, but what about sumatra? For some reasons I want to use this PDF viewer.